# P = NP -> EXP has circuit size O(2^n/n)

Tags: computational-complexity

How does this proof work / can someone provide a link to a paper? This is exercise 6.7 of Computational Complexity a Modern Approach. I know the following:

(1) P = NP -> EXP = NEXP (by padding)
(2) exists f: {0,1}^n -> {0,1} that takes at least O(2^n/n) , by pigeon hole
(3) any f:{0,1}^n -> {0,1} can be done in O(2^n/n), by Shannon's clever result from 49
(4) Looks like I'm supposed t use NEXP to "guess" a circuit of some sort.

I've also googled around, and there's references to some famous work by Razabov's work, I can't figure out which paper.

Question: What step am I missing in proving this classical, well known result?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If $P = NP$, then $E = EH := E^{PH}$. You can easily define the lexicographically first truth table of a Boolean function $f\colon\{0,1\}^n\to\{0,1\}$ with the maximum circuit complexity (which is $\sim2^n/n$ by Shannon and Lupanov) in $E^{\Sigma^p_2}$: find the maximum circuit complexity $s_\max$ by binary search using an oracle for “there exists a function with circuit complexity $\ge s$”, then find $f$ by binary search using an oracle for “there exists $g\le_{\mathrm{Lex}}f$ with circuit complexity $s_\max$”. (This argument is essentially due to [Kannan](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0019-9958%2882%2990382-5) who states it with $NE^{\Sigma^p_2}\cap coNE^{\Sigma^p_2}$. The strengthening with $E^{\Sigma^p_2}$ is basically folklore, an explicit proof is given in Lemma 2 of [Miltersen, Vinodchadran & Watanabe](http://www.cse.unl.edu/~vinod/papers/subexp.ps).)

Comment: @ Emil: where do you use P = NP? PH \subset E, so E = E^PH . What am I missing?

Comment: It's not true that $E^E=E$. Note that since exponential time is available, the oracle may be supplied with an exponentially long query! Thus, for example, $E^{NP}$ contains NE (and coNE).

Comment: @ Emil: My bad. I confused E and EXP. I meant to type:

PH \subset EXP, so EXP = EXP^PH. Does EXP^EXP not equal EXP?

Comment: E or EXP does not make much of a difference here. $EXP^{EXP}$ does not equal EXP. In fact, $EXP^{EXP}=EEXP:=DTIME(2^{2^{n^{O(1)}}})$ by a padding argument (an EEXP problem can be computed by an EXP machine $M$ when the inputs are given with exponentially long padding; we can generate the padding by another EXP machine, and then pass it as an oracle query to $M$).

Comment: @ Emil: Let $M_1, M_2 \in EXP$; $M_1$ using DTIME($2^{p1(n)}$), $M_2$ using DTIME($2^{p2(n)}$). Then, I can simulate $M_1^{M_2}$ in DTIME ($2^{ p1(n) + p2(n) }$). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are ignoring the fact which I am now repeating for the third time, namely that oracle queries can have exponential length. During your simulation, $M_1$ makes some queries to $M_2$. Since the running time of $M_1$ is $2^{p_1(n)}$, the oracle queries can also have length up to $m=2^{p_1(n)}$. When $M_2$ is simulated on inputs of size $m$, it can take time $2^{p_2(m)}=2^{p_2\left(2^{p_1(n)}\right)}$, which is doubly exponential in $n$.

Comment: Hi Email. Arora and Barak explicitly request in the preface of their book that people do not post online answers to the exercises in the book. Based on the questions of this user, it seems to me that this user is posting a number of homework question on MO. I am not sure, but IIRC people don't answer homework questions on Mathoverflow.